# Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'ISPICKVAL()'. Expected 2, received 3

Tags: workflow

```
AND(            
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Cancellation Requested", "Contacted Info Sent"),            
    ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Cancellation confirmed") 
)
```

I am trying to add another picklist value in the work flow and it is giving me an error.

Please can somebody help.

Comment: Can you describe the business logic you're trying to implement with this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below,

```
  AND(            
        OR (
           ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName),"Cancellation Requested")
           ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Contacted Info Sent")
        ),            
        ISPICKVAL(StageName,"Cancellation confirmed") 
    )
```

Dont forget to accept answer if it works. Tia